# UIRefreshControl layout wrong in UIScrollView with left/right contentInset

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uikit, uirefreshcontrol

If I'm using a `UIScrollView` with a non-zero left/right `contentInset` and add a `UIRefreshControl`, the refresh is positioned incorrectly making the UI and animation look bizarre.

```swift
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 40, bottom: 0, right: 40)
scrollView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

I'd prefer not to hack the layout of the refresh control, but can't find a way to get this to position correctly.

Here's a screenshot of the bug:
[image]

And here's an animation from the view inspector:

[image]

Comment: If there is no constraint error on the console, could it be one missing on the scrollview ? looks like refreshControl keep the storyboard size.

Comment: Is there a cell there too? Because it looks like it might be going off the right side of the view. Could you unclip the views to make sure the scroll view is correctly positioned? One of the icons at the bottom of debug code hierarchy does that.

Comment: @EricD this demo is using Auto Layout, but I can repro it exactly the same using plain frame math.

Comment: @KyleBashour no subviews in the scrollview :(

Comment: Is this on a stand alone scroll view? Possibly just the undefined behavior Apple mentions when using a UIRefreshControl outside of a UITableViewController. Does the same bug happen when setting the inset of a table view w/ a refresh control?

Comment: @JohnBrophy ya just a standalone UIScrollView. UIScrollView received a refreshControl property as of iOS 10, so this should work. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2127691-refreshcontrol

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Strange that the UIRefreshControl docs still have that warning https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it locally by creating a `UIRefreshControl` subclass, but this is definitely a hack.

```
override var frame: CGRect {
    get { return super.frame }
    set {
        var newFrame = newValue
        if let superScrollView = superview as? UIScrollView {
            newFrame.origin.x = superScrollView.frame.minX - superScrollView.contentInset.left
        }
        super.frame = newFrame
    }
}
```

I'll file a radar since I'm starting to think this is a bug in UIKit.

Comment: Since the refresh control is a subview of the scroll view, I actually don't think you care about the scroll view's frame:

`newFrame.origin.x = -superScrollView.contentInset.left`

Comment: in my opinion it will be even better: 
newFrame.origin.y = newValue.minY - (superScrollView.contentInset.top / 2)